# Visual Studio 2022 build takes forever

Tags: nuget-package-restore, visual-studio-2022

Visual Studio 2022 build takes forever and the same project works fine with Visual Studio 2019 on the same machine

On build, got NuGet package restore error:

NuGet package restore failed. Please see Error List window for detailed warnings and errors.
Error occurred while restoring NuGet packages: The operation failed as details for project API.Tests could not be loaded.

Tried clearing packages cache, resetting settings, deleting .vs folder & also clearing %temp% prefetch

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I've just starting trying to use VS2022 and NuGet is completely nonfunctional.

Comment: Hi there. Just checking if you managed to resolve the issue. Installed VS 2022 today and have the same issue. No dependencies are displaying

Comment: I also have an issue with insane build times. It occurred just as i migrated a project from a packages config to PackageReference. Curious if you were trying something similar?

Comment: 5 months old!!! Any updates?!?!

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately, it is now fixed in the latest Visual Studio 17.5.0 Preview 6.0
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/

There is an alternative in this answer, but while it helps when using command line, it is still very annoying for anything inside Visual Studio 2022. I am hitting it on many scenarios, like trying to run tests after build was successful.

[VIsual Studio 2022 stuck on Restoring Nuget packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73187972/visual-studio-2022-stuck-on-restoring-nuget-packages/75466598#75466598)